# How to Display a JSON list to be READABLE?

Tags: python, json, firebase

I have a JSON string here from Firebase. I'm fetching this via Pythons Pyrebase.
However, there's one big problem.

The JSON I'm gettting is a list, for example a checklist:

```
u'Wardrode u'No u'Behind Table u'No u'dust-dree
```

It is a Json string but I replaced some annyoing strings:

```
 Using 

    result1 = result1.replace("u'", "")
    result1 = result1.replace("{", "")
    result1 = result1.replace("}", "")
    result1 = result1.replace("'", "")
    result1 = result1.replace(":", "")
    result1 = result1.replace("\u", "")
```

I want to replace Yes and No with  a newline so that it becomes a proper list when I display it at HTML

Here's my full code:

```
    result1 = firebase.get('/Rooms/Room1/2017-11-29/Inspection/Scan-in/Inspector/', None)

    for key in result1.keys():
        key = sorted(result1.keys())
        currentdate = key

        print currentdate

    for key in result1.keys():
       inspector = key


    print result1
```

I wanted to make a decent and readable output using the one-line json list that I am gettign from firebase.

It looks like this:

```
{
  "Rooms" : {
    "Room1" : {
      "2017-11-29" : {
        "Inspection" : {
          "Scan-in" : {
            "Inspector" : {
              "brix" : {
                "Nov 29, 2017 11:20:15 PM" : {
                  "Checklist" : {
                    "1 Bible, Environment Card, Telephone Directory,  Amenity Card, Room Attendant’s Card,  Asmara Spa Tent Card, TV remote?" : "No",
                    "1 bath gel?" : "No",
                    "1 bath mat hanging on shower glass door handle?" : "No",
                    "1 bath soap" : "No",
                    "1 extra pillow with pillow cover?" : "No",
                    "1 facial tissue in a tissue box" : "No",
                    "1 lotion" : "No",
                    "1 pringles, 1 cashew nut, 1 cup noodles (placed in the coffee tray on the writing desk)?" : "No",
                    "1 sanitary bag" : "No",
                    "1 set of iron and board?" : "No",
                    "1 set of laundry list and bag?" : "No",
                    "1 shampoo?" : "No",
                    "1 shower cap" : "No",
                    "1 vanity kit" : "No",
                    "2 Tumbler overturned with coaster" : "No",
                    "2 bath towels - on the towel rack?" : "No",
                    "2 bathrobes?" : "No",
                    "2 coke, 2 sprite, 1 C2 lemon, 1 C2 apple, 1 pineapple juice, 1 orange juice, 1 mineral water, 2 San Mig light, 2 pale pilsen?" : "No",
                    "2 cups and saucers (for Mountain Wing" : "No",
                    "2 dental kit" : "No",
                    "2 face towels – on vanity counter (For suites, premier and VIPs)?" : "No",
                    "2 hand towels ?" : "No",
                    "2 mugs overturned with coaster (for Lake Wing)?" : "No",
                    "2 pairs of slippers?" : "No",
                    "6 Hangers?" : "No",
                    "Air conditioning temperature is in good working condition  Set at 17o C, low speed" : "No",
                    "Appearance door surface in good condition" : "Yes",
                    "Appearance door surface- in good condition" : "No",
                    "Appearance of the bed – neat and sheet tightened?" : "No",
                    "Arrangement of the sofa and table  in order" : "No",
                    "Bedhead free from dust" : "No",
                    "Bedsheet and pillow cases clean" : "No",
                    "Behind table - dust" : "No",
                    "Ceiling – no cobweb, water marks and crack lines" : "No",
                    "Check appearance of the glass – clean" : "No",
                    "Check the table surface – clean" : "No",
                    "Check underneath cushion" : "No",
                    "Coffee tray with 3 coffee sticks, 3 creamer, 3 white sugar, 3 brown sugar, 1 equal or sweetener, 3 lipton tea, 2 mineral water, 3 cocktail napkin ?" : "No",
                    "Compendium with 1 stationary pad, 1 envelope, channel guide?" : "No",
                    "Curtains are neat, presentable with hooks all intact and curtain rod" : "No",
                    "Door surface in good condition" : "No",
                    "Door surface – clean" : "No",
                    "Drawers – clean and dust-free" : "No",
                    "Dust bin with liner" : "No",
                    "Dustbin under the table is clean" : "No",
                    "Elsafe open or working?" : "No",
                    "Entrance louver clean and dust-free" : "No",
                    "Eye viewer and fire escape plan in order" : "No",
                    "Floor vacuumed and stain free" : "No",
                    "Free from rubbish under the bed" : "No",
                    "Fridge is cold and clean" : "No",
                    "Glass panel and door -clean" : "No",
                    "Guest Comment Card?" : "No",
                    "Hairdryer" : "No",
                    "Handbasin, vanity counter, vanity mirror and shaving mirror – clean" : "No",
                    "Happenings This Week" : "No",
                    "Key card holder – in working order" : "No",
                    "Lamp or light" : {
                      "diffuser clean and working" : "No"
                    },
                    "Let the door close by itself to test the door closure – in working order" : "No",
                    "Lights and switches are working" : {
                      "Remarks" : ""
                    },
                    "Lights in working order" : "No",
                    "Luggage bench fabric top is clean" : "No",
                    "Magazine" : "No",
                    "Minibar Voucher or Slip" : "No",
                    "Pencil?" : "No",
                    "Privacy Sign or Make Up Room Sign" : "No",
                    "Pull the curtains to test if they are working" : "No",
}
}
```

I want to make it readable and understandable by removing the unescessary text. I can do that via

```
    result1 =  str(result1)
    result1 = result1.replace("u'", "")
    result1 = result1.replace("{", "")
    result1 = result1.replace("}", "")
    result1 = result1.replace("'", "")
    result1 = result1.replace(":", "")
    result1 = result1.replace("\u", "")
```

Which makes the input I have in the first image to this:

[image]

However I am unable to do:

```
    result1 = result1.replace("No,", "No\n")
    result1 = result1.replace("Yes,", "Yes\n")
```

Which I wanted to do in order to sort out the checklist.
The string must be on a newline when it finds a Yes or No. But still displays its value.

Any new ideas on how I am able to sort these data is also welcome too.

Sample data that I want:

Scan in : `brix Nov 29, 2017 112015 PM Checklist Coffee tray with 3 coffee sticks, 3 creamer, 3 white sugar, 3 brown sugar, 1 equal or sweetener, 3 lipton tea, 2 mineral water, 3 cocktail napkin ? No`

```
Luggage bench fabric top is clean No

1 facial tissue in a tissue box No

Towel Reminder No, 1 pringles, 1 cashew nut, 1 cup noodles (placed in the coffee tray on the writing desk)? No
```

... and so on.

How can I do that? Please help

Comment: Using `str.replace` operations for this is the wrong tool for the job. You're mangling time strings, and turning unicode escapes like `\u2013` (which is an en dash `–`) into numbers. You should be using `json.loads` to parse this JSON data. And then you can print it how you want by iterating over the data and printing it with appropriate `format` calls. However, if you want specific help with this you should post a sample of the JSON data as text, so that people can test their code on your data. We can't load text from an image file.

Comment: Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). That question mainly talks about posting code as an image, but it also applies to data.

Comment: It's not clear how you're generating HTML from this, but if you want line breaks, newlines in python aren't translated into HTML paragraphs

Comment: By the way, you want `for key in sorted(result1.keys())`... Don't do that sorted within the loop and reset the key variable

Answer (score 0):

> Here's my full code

I don't think so... From the json you gave and the code shown, it looks like you skipped over the `brix` key. And the image shown is not a console output, so you've not shown the HTML generation.

Anyways, your string replacement is just the wrong solution. You're looking at Python's unicode strings within a dictionary. If you parsed the content, you should not see `u''`, or `{}` characters.

For example, try something like this

```
x = "'brix" 
print("Scan in " + x) 
dates = sorted(result1[x].keys())
for d in dates:
    print(d) 
    for check, status in result1[x][d]['Checklist'].items():
        print(check, status)
```